# AngularJS - Setting height same as width

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have div with percent width, and I would like to write script in AngularJS that will set div height same as width. I already done this in pure JavaScript.

```
function heightSameAsWidth(){
  var w = document.getElementById("cc1").offsetWidth;
  document.getElementById("cc1").style.height = w+"px";
}
```

Comment: You can use `ng-style` directive. `<div id="cc1" ng-style="{height: w + 'px'}">`. Set `w` as a scope variable.

Comment: did you know you can achieve that with pure CSS? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using an attribute directive. If the component's percent width doesn't change, you can write a function that will be invoked in the directive's postLink function, for example:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  function setHeight() {
    element.css("height", element.css("width"));
  }

  setHeight();
}
```

On the other hand, if your element's percentage width might change, then another approach can be where the width is stored in the parent's scope (similar to another solution by Kavindra in the comments above). Wrap this element in a component instead, and specify the width as a binding. For example:

```
<square-component width="$ctrl.width"></square-component>
```

Then, define a method called setDimensions() in your component's controller, that will set the width and height equal to the value of the width binding. In the $onChanges method of your component, check when the width changes, and invoke your setDimensions() method again. This way, you can change the width anytime, using JavaScript, from the parent component.

```
$onChanges(changes) {
   if (changes.width) {
       setDimensions();
   }
}

setDimensions() {
   this.$element.css("width", this.width);
   this.$element.css("height", this.height);
}
```